# Can __int64 be stored in sql server Int if value is within __int32 bounds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, 64-bit, type-conversion

I wonder if anyone knows whether it is safe to store a 64-bit long long or __int64 (or ptrdiff_t at x64 configuration) into an SQL server INT datatype _given that the value I want to store in the database is first checked to be between INT32_MIN and INT32_MAX_ for instance?

Will SQL Server simply truncate the __int64 datatype by cutting off MSBs or will it actually convert first to INT datatype and then store it. Because if it simply Cuts the value it will be bad for negative __int64 values.

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get an "Arithmetic overflow" error if your number is too big for the SQL int datatype. If the number fits in the storage bounds of the int datatype then SQL will perform an implicit cast. You can use the following code to test it...

```
declare @num int
declare @bignum bigint

set @bignum = cast(POWER(2,30) as bigint)*2-1
-- First assignment, doesn't error
set @num = @bignum

select @bignum, @num

set @bignum += 1

-- Second assignment, does error
set @num = @bignum
select @bignum, @num
```

The first assignment works perfectly. The second errors.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the code sample as well! :)
Good that it seems to actually make an implicit cast instead of just truncating bits.